Why the Google Play store listing not collecting data in store listing experiment
My Android app has a large number of downloads from Google Play ( organic and inorganic) but in the store listing experiment it's not showing any results
There is a high audience from Turkey but in the app store listing there are no results of any of the variants of Turkish customized experiment
What can be the reasons for this issue?

There are multiple reason why this could happen:

You did not wait enough: sometimes it takes 48 hours for experiment to start. and if you are using Retained first-time installers as a goal it could take another 48 hours.
You have a policy violation or content warning in app store: Google play will not tell you that you need to fix these first but the experiment will not start unless you address the issues.
Your experiment is still in review



The variable you did use in the experiment are targeting very small audience, or you are having contradicting variables (e.g Chinese language in France, this will target a very small audience)

the date of experiment are still in future.


